# Achieving true separation of concerns between HTML, CSS & JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bem

Using the following HTML structure, how best do I achieve separation of concerns between HTML, CSS & JS?

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-nav js-site-nav">
  <ul class="site-nav__list">
    <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link is-active">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/wGVGxj

First of all, this example doesn't seem truly de-coupled. I'm finding that class naming system doesn't lend itself to being separated. When trying to target the links I'd still need to use the `.site-nav__link` selector somewhere in the JS.

Using a JS hook class on each link seems like a move in the right
direction. Would adding `.js-site-nav__link` class on each link be an
improvement?

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-nav">
  <ul class="site-nav__list">
    <li class="site-nav__item js-site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="site-nav__item js-site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link is-active">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

That doesn't appeal to me greatly because although not intrinsically tied to the presentational class, using the entire BEM name would still make it hard to make any structural changes and I don't see a gain over just using `.site-nav__link`.

I might consider a class name like `js-link`, but generalising leads to other problems. Is targeting `.js-site-nav .js-link` going to give me best of everything?

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-nav">
  <ul class="site-nav__list">
    <li class="site-nav__item js-link"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="site-nav__item js-link"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link is-active">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I feel this is truly de-coupled, but is it as good as it's going to get?

Thanks @claudios for providing a simple example which has a nice JS hook, `js-add` which includes a verb which helps. Something like this works well but wouldn't be appropriate in my example. Feeling that a JS hook along the lines of `js-toggle-link` might be starting to get to something well-structured.

Source: HTML taken from the following talk (jumps to relevant part at 17 mins in)...
https://vimeo.com/album/3953264/video/166790749#t=17m0s

Comment: *"This example doesn't seem truly de-coupled"* requires us to watch a video to understand your issues. Questions need to be self contained. In order for us to understand you need to itemize example in question itself as well as define what your expectations are. Using prefixed classes is very common

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. This is regarding the HTML example I included later in the question and in the provided Codepen

Comment: Well again...questions should be self contained and external links only used to support what is actually in the question. We shouldn't have to go off site to fully review the issues you have. demos in sandboxes are helpful after we read and understand the full problem

Comment: I've edited the question so that the video is supplied as a footnote. I'll try to re-word the question further to be more succinct.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to evaluate your expectations and some of this will elicit opinionated answers

Comment: I'd not say BEM is used for decoupling (as, separate CSS from HTML - you have `<link>` for that), but for organisation purposes. This way anybody looking at your code will know "ok, this is the navigation, these are elements, that is a modifier". I'd think `js-` represents all classes that are needed to make javascript work - as, are used by `jquery` to attach events. In this aspect, yes, this code is organised, and glancing at it you can determine what is its purpose.

Comment: I see the advantages of de-coupling (there are many cases though where it would be superfluous and overshoot the goal), but I'd prefer to use classes only for styling, and put hooks in an attribute (data- or custom).

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is you wanted a good way to decouple html, css and javascript. Base on my experience I would suggest using prefix for all js.

For example: `js-*`

Imagine if you have a button like `<button class="add">Add</button>` then you wanted to put a js on it then this can be rewritten as.

```
<button class="js-add add">Add</button>
```

Now if this button is something more special and need to be different from all buttons with a class `add` then you can write

```
<button class="js-add add-special">Add</button>
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: This illustrates the idea well. It looks and feels correct in your example. A class name for the js hook with a verb such as `js-add` or `js-save` would sit next to a presentational class name like (taking my example) `site-nav__link` nicely, but what's the best class name for navigation links in my example? 

My suggestion was `js-link`. How about `js-toggle` or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

Actually BEM is about opposite idea.

Think in terms of blocks (components) which know everything about themselves: markup (HTML), view (CSS) and behaviour (JS).

So instead of separation of these three, BEM says one should have them together.

Getting back to your example with `site-nav` you may have all your JS delegated to the block itself and operate with its elements as with internal API of a block (`is-active` should become a modifier of `site-nav__link`).

Please take a look at documentation on bem.info to learn more: https://en.bem.info/methodology/js/

Comment: I have used the approach you've suggested in the past, but have moved away from it because it didn't provide the flexibility that I wish for. We can't modify our scss without changing selectors in the JavaScript. Binding JS onto the same class that is used for presentation is fragile and makes it hard to change or re-use. The separation of concerns is a principle that is all about maintenance.

I recommend watching the entire talk that I posted in the original post. I think you'll enjoy it. 

Or for further reading, this: http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/

Comment: There are many cases where you should separate different entities from each other, but I'm gonna agree with @tadatuta about the primal BEM idea. upd: Btw, in your current case js-link looks like a separate block that should be mixed with site-nav__link. Depends on what you put semantically in these entities.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using such naming just complicates things, while nowadays you can organize your elements and events quiet easily using `SASS` in `CSS` and `OOP` coding in `JS` and selecting the elements in the correct hierarchy.

**You have to name your elements and events as simple as possible.**

let me elaborate:

let's say we wanna implement an structure like you've given example:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-nav js-site-nav">
  <ul class="site-nav__list">
    <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="site-nav__item"><a href="#" class="site-nav__link is-active">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

while this is really neat to name your elements in this hierarchal structure, it'll get kinda confusing after a while, plus if someone new comes to the project and sees the naming, well, let's just say it'll take them a while to remember the names all by themselves (not cheating from the other codes).

if I were to implement this structure it'd be something like:

**HTML**

```
<nav role="navigation" class="site-nav js">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**SCSS**

```
.site-nav{
    //styling here

    &.js{
    //styling here
    }

    ul{
        //styling here

        li{
            //styling here

            a{
               //styling here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now let's say I wanna write an event for the `a` previously known as `a.site-nav__link`:

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('.site-nav ul li a').addEventListener(eventName, function() {});
```

the hierarchy makes you find the elements as easy as possible and you'll never forget the name of those kinds of elements.

now let's take a look at the `.js` and why do we use it?

in general you don't need to use a "js class" for every element that is going to be used in `js`, so why do we use it? let me explain that with an example.

let's say we have a button called `.button` with some styles.

**SCSS**

```
.button{
    //Some styles
}
```

we want **some** of these buttons (with the same style) to grow size after being clicked, so we add a `.js` class to them to know that they're being manipulated with `js` and handle them easier.

```
document.querySelector('.button.js').addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.className+=' clicked';
});
```

and in the `CSS` we write:

```
.button{
    //Some styles
    &.js{
        .clicked{
            transform:scale(1.1);
        }
    }
}
```

it's just that simple!

on the other hand if we didn't wanna use the `.js` class (which can be used on other elements as well because we're never using it alone and it'll always come with another class or id as well as `.active`) we had to write another class for those buttons, but with a little hierarchy we write **less code** and **keep things organized** also we'll never have to cheat from other scripts because the name of the elements and events are so damn hard to remember!

Comment: I'd not advise OP to drop BEM - while his example is simple enough, it's quite handy to have in large projects

Comment: agreed but it's not as simple, also BEM makes larger projects a bit confusing after a while, specially for new-comers.

Comment: If the alternative is: let's allow every CSS guy to name their classes whatever way they want, so, in one project there're things like `class='my-class myClass blue_button'`, then I gladly prefer BEM

Comment: I never said that everyone can name classes the way they want, I just said that it needs to be as simple as possible, which means everyone needs to use the class `.active` to show the activeness of the element for example. so `my-class` is always going to be `my-class` and we tell the difference between these `my-class` elements by their hierarchy in the document, not by using these kinds of names `.your-element__the-parent--my-class`, which will be much more difficult to remember in a long going project

Comment: I've found that BEM is a necessary evil for large-scale front-end architecture. I don't like it but it works. I think that the same question could be be posed without the presence of BEM-based classes

Comment: after all naming is an option, not a standard, we could create our own standards according to the needs of the project and make them as simple as possible, just use a sheet to write them down and hand them to every new-comers, they'll get it in minutes!

Comment: my personal experience, BEM makes things confusing and if all the team members are not pros, you'll end up cleaning up all the codes they've written in order to get rid of conflicts and mis-spellings

Comment: @Amin Jafari - fair point and BEM provides you with rules on how your naming scheme should be. I like it that you want to keep things as simple as possible, and yes, while in the navigation example it's valid to drop the class names for individual items, it becomes necessary when objects need to be described (when I saw BEM for the first time I found it quirky, but now when I don't have to see different conventions on new projects, I'm a happier person)

Comment: exactly my point in the comment above yours `my personal experience...`